# Auction contract example with metadata

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program

In the example of NFT Auction, I am thinking about potential scenarios where certain JSON metadata an NFT was minted with, happens to be required in some arbitrary logic within auction process (artist info, description, etc.).

Could NFT metadata be extracted/parsed straight from Plutus offchain code or should this info be handled completely "offchain" and then putting back into datuum when auction starts off?

Also, is it already possible in Plutus to mint NFT tokens with arbitrary JSON metadata in a similar fashion as cardano-cli already does?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.